# Use sed to replace a part of a line with a variable

Tags: text-processing, sed

So right now I have a variable

```
var1='batman'
```

I also have a file `wrong.txt` that reads as follows

```
John="Superman lives in Gotham City."
John="Superman's parents were killed in Crime Alley."
James="Superman does not have a bat-mobile."
```

Now I want to change the file's contents using sed. Obviously, I need to replace Superman with batman. 
I tried doing it with sed, but there were no changes made to the file.

Here is what I did

```
sed -i -e "s/John=\"Superman/John=\"$var1/g" wrong.txt
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: same here.. worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, need to make an edit.

Comment: this one also worked for me

Comment: wait, why the `" ' " ${var1}" '` ?

Comment: After the edits which have significantly changed both the file and the command, it still works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\(John="\)Superman/\1'"$var1/g" <in file
```

...ought to work.